# System.Web.HttpContext in web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, httpcontext

I am using a dll file in my web api project using .net core. In the dll file System.Web.HttpContext is used. So when I am calling a function of that dll I am getting the error "***Could not load type 'System.Web.HttpContext' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.***"

How can I solve this?
Thanks

Comment: which version of .NET does your project have?

Comment: You can use [fusion logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net) to get detailed information about assemblies that fail to load.

Comment: Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.4, 
   Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.12,  
   Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.1.0,   
   Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.4,  
   Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.12,   
   Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.4